# DisplayMemberPath not working, TreeView, Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, treeview

Okay, so the DisplayMemberPath isn't working at all, i have tried all day to fix it and nothing i found on the internet works... I tried to do all of the stuff only with the code and it still didn't work...
Here is the xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="gdMain" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:CountryList x:Key="smth"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <sdk:TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource smth}, Path=getCountries}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="tvMain" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Transparent">
    </sdk:TreeView>
</Grid>
```

And here is the code behind:

```
public class CountryList 
{
    private ObservableCollection<Country> ocl = new ObservableCollection<Country>();
    public CountryList()
    {
        ocl.Add(new Country()
        {
            Name = "Bolivia, Plurinational State of",
            Alpha2 = "BO",
            Alpha3 = "BOL",
            Iso = "ISO 3166-2:BO",
            FonPrefix = "+591"
        });
        ocl.Add(new Country()
        {
            Name = "China",
            Alpha2 = "CN",
            Alpha3 = "CHN",
            Iso = "ISO 3166-2:CN",
            FonPrefix = "+86"
        });
        ocl.Add(new Country()
        {
            Name = "Andorra",
            Alpha2 = "AD",
            Alpha3 = "AND",
            Iso = "ISO 3166-2:AD",
            FonPrefix = "+376"
        });
        ocl.Add(new Country()
        {
            Name = "Moldova, Republic of",
            Alpha2 = "MD",
            Alpha3 = "MDA",
            Iso = "ISO 3166-2:MD",
            FonPrefix = "+373"
        });
        ocl.Add(new Country()
        {
            Name = "Poland",
            Alpha2 = "PL",
            Alpha3 = "POL",
            Iso = "ISO 3166-2:PL",
            FonPrefix = "+48"
        });
        ocl.Add(new Country()
        {
            Name = "Iceland",
            Alpha2 = "IS",
            Alpha3 = "ISL",
            Iso = "ISO 3166-2:IS",
            FonPrefix = "+354"
        });
        ocl.Add(new Country()
        {
            Name = "Colombia",
            Alpha2 = "CO",
            Alpha3 = "COL",
            Iso = "ISO 3166-2:CO",
            FonPrefix = "+57"
        });
        ocl.Add(new Country()
        {
            Name = "Bahrain",
            Alpha2 = "BH",
            Alpha3 = "BHR",
            Iso = "ISO 3166-2:BH",
            FonPrefix = "+973"
        });
        ocl.Add(new Country()
        {
            Name = "Dominican Republic",
            Alpha2 = "DO",
            Alpha3 = "DOM",
            Iso = "ISO 3166-2:DO",
            FonPrefix = "+1 809, +1 829, +1 849"
        });
        ocl.Add(new Country()
        {
            Name = "Nicaragua",
            Alpha2 = "NI",
            Alpha3 = "NIC",
            Iso = "ISO 3166-2:NI",
            FonPrefix = "+505"
        });
    }
    public  ObservableCollection<Country> getCountries
    {
        get
        {   
            return ocl;     
        }
    }
}
```

The constructor of the user control which holds the treeview.

```
public partial class ucTreeView : ucBaseClass
{

    public ucTreeView()
    {

            InitializeComponent();
            tvMain.ItemsSource = new CountryList().getCountries;
            tvMain.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
            this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set the DataContext of the form?

Comment: No i didn't, actually. I don't know how to use that...
I just added this to the sdk:TreeView XAML:  DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource smth}}", and it still isn't working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, what i needed is to add the ItemTemplate and the DataTemplate, like this:

```
<sdk:TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource smth}, Path=getCountries}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="223" Margin="135,58,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="243">
        <sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </sdk:TreeView>
```

Now it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as you did not set the DataContext of the application here is what you have to do (very very very simplified version):

Under your Window you should have the following:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> empList { get; set; }
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        empList = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
        empList.Add(new Employee("John", "Michael"));
        empList.Add(new Employee("Freddy", "Rajec"));

        this.DataContext = this;//important line, wihtout this line your window will not get access to objects
    }
}
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public Employee(string sName, string sSurname)
    {
        Name = sName;
        Surname = sSurname;
    }
}
```

and then in your Window you would set the following:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding empList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

In case you are using MVVM pattern it is slightly different (as the data Context becomes the view model) but concept is more or less the same.

**EDIT**

How about something following:

```
public partial class ucTreeView : ucBaseClass
{
    public ObservableCollection<CountryList> country_List{ get; set; }
    public ucTreeView()
    {
            InitializeComponent();
            country_List = new ObservableCollection<CountryList>();
            CountryList cList = new CountryList();
            country_List = cList.getCountries;//retrieve country list
            this.DataContext = this
    }
}
```

and under your Window:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding country_List}, DisplayMemberPath="InputWhateverYouWantToShowHere"}
```

Comment: Can you share code where you initialize **CountryList** class?

Comment: if i do it by code it looks like this:
InitializeComponent();
tvMain.ItemsSource = new CountryList().getCountries;
tvMain.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
this.DataContext = this;

tvMain == TreeView

And the only thing it shows is the path to the Country class

Comment: Please add it to your original code (at the bottom) as this is hardly readable

Comment: Edited...There is alot of code i can't show. The ucTreeView is a User Control that holds the treeview

Comment: I believe you meant for country_list to be of type Country? I tried your updated solution and it still doesn't work.. Thanks alot for your effort btw.. :D